# How do I find the set of Site Pages to which I have assigned unique permissions?

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am the owner of a SharePoint Online site, and I have a handful of pages that I wanted to hide from Visitors, so I went to the Site Pages folder and clicked Manage Access for each file I wanted to hide, and I clicked the name of the SiteVisitors group and clicked Stop Sharing. The result is that Visitors cannot navigate or even see those pages in a Search. Now I want to restore the access for Visitors.

BUT, let's say I forgot the names of the pages that I hid. ***I*** can still see the pages because I am the Owner, but I forgot which pages the Visitors cannot see. So how do I generate a list of all pages that have non-standard permissions?

Answer (score 0):

You can get all pages with unqiue permissions in your Site Pages library using below CSOM powershell.

```
#Load SharePoint CSOM Assemblies
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server 
Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server 
Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"

#Function to call a non-generic method Load
Function Invoke-LoadMethod() {
param([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientObject]$Object = $(throw "Please provide a Client Object"),[string]$PropertyName) 
$ctx = $Object.Context
$load = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext].GetMethod("Load") 
$type = $Object.GetType()
$clientLoad = $load.MakeGenericMethod($type)  
$Parameter = [System.Linq.Expressions.Expression]::Parameter(($type), $type.Name)
$Expression = [System.Linq.Expressions.Expression]::Lambda([System.Linq.Expressions.Expression]::Convert([System.Linq.Expressions.Expression]::PropertyOrField($Parameter,$PropertyName),[System.Object] ), $($Parameter))
$ExpressionArray = [System.Array]::CreateInstance($Expression.GetType(), 1)
$ExpressionArray.SetValue($Expression, 0)
$clientLoad.Invoke($ctx,@($Object,$ExpressionArray))
}  
#Define Parameter values
$SiteURL="https://crescent.sharepoint.com/sites/PMO"
$ListName="Site Pages"

Try {
  #Setup Credentials to connect
  $Cred= Get-Credential
  $Credentials = New-Object 
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Cred.Username, $Cred.Password)

#Setup the context
$Ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL)
$Ctx.Credentials = $Credentials
      
#Get All Lists of the web
$List = $Ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($ListName)
$Ctx.Load($List)
$Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
Write-host "Total List Items Found:"$List.ItemCount

#Query to Get 2000 items from the list
$Query = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery
$Query.ViewXml = "<View Scope='RecursiveAll'><RowLimit>2000</RowLimit></View>"

#Batch process list items - to mitigate list threshold issue on larger lists
Do {  
    $ListItems = $List.GetItems($Query)
    $Ctx.Load($ListItems)
    $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()

    $Query.ListItemCollectionPosition = $ListItems.ListItemCollectionPosition

    #Loop through each List item
    ForEach($ListItem in $ListItems)
    {
        Invoke-LoadMethod -Object $ListItem -PropertyName "HasUniqueRoleAssignments"
        $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
        if ($ListItem.HasUniqueRoleAssignments -eq $true)
        {        
            Write-Host -f Green "List Item '$($ListItem["Title"])' with ID '$($ListItem.ID)' has Unique Permissions"
        }
        else
        {
            Write-Host -f Yellow "List Item '$($ListItem["Title"])' with ID '$($ListItem.ID)' is inhering Permissions from the Parent"
        }
    }
} While ($Query.ListItemCollectionPosition -ne $null)

}
Catch {
  write-host -f Red "Error Checking Unique Permissions!" $_.Exception.Message
}
```

Or use PnP PowerShell.

```
#Set Variables
$SiteURL = "https://crescent.sharepoint.com/sites/PMO"
$ListName = "Site Pages"

#Connect to PnP Online
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $SiteURL -UseWebLogin

#Get all list items in batches
$ListItems = Get-PnPListItem -List $ListName -PageSize 2000

#Iterate through each list item
ForEach($ListItem in $ListItems)
{
    #Check if the Item has unique permissions
    $HasUniquePermissions = Get-PnPProperty -ClientObject $ListItem -Property 
"HasUniqueRoleAssignments"
    If($HasUniquePermissions)
    {
        Write-Host -f Green "List Item '$($ListItem["Title"])' with ID '$($ListItem.ID)' has Unique Permissions"
    }
    Else
    {
        Write-Host -f Yellow "List Item '$($ListItem["Title"])' with ID '$($ListItem.ID)' is inhering Permissions from its Parent"
    }    
}
```

Reference: [SharePoint Online: Get All List Items with Unique Permissions using PowerShell](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2017/03/sharepoint-online-get-all-list-items-with-unique-permissions-using-powershell.html)

You can also delete all unique permissions in a library using PowerShell. Reference: [SharePoint Online: Delete Unique Permissions for All Items in a List using PowerShell](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2016/02/powershell-to-delete-unique-permissions-for-all-list-items-sharepoint-online.html)